# React Native with Openfire XMPP

Tags: react-native, xmpp, openfire

I am looking for a way to connect react native app with openfire xmpp server. I find difficulties to find libraries for this. If anyone knows, please suggest me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there are many XMPP libraries available for for JavaScript. Here is a small incomplete list in random order

- StanzaJS
- Strophe.js
- xmpp.js

Comment: I tried xmpp.js and Strophe.js but it is not working due node core module issue. So, Stanza.js is working completely with using node core module by importing "node-libs-react-native" to project.